# Logitech K800 keyboard not working

Tags: logitech-keyboard

I tried replacing the batteries of my Logitech K800 wireless keyboard, but it’s still flashing red! What do I do to fix it!

Comment: Hello, and welcome here. Did you install the correct batteries? Most keyboard only accept Alkaline or Rechargeable batteries.  If you installed Heavy Duty, Super Heavy Duty or Zinc batteries are usually not good for this application.

Answer (score 0):

You need NiMH type batteries for this keyboard. Try replacing it with those.